# Powershell Get-MsolAccountSku returns Microsoft.Online.Administration.AccountSkuDetails

Tags: powershell, office365

I have a script to be able to assign office 365 licenses to my tenant's user via powershell, however I have a problem, which is, when I try to read the tenant's available licenses through powershell, I get it without any problem (https://i.stack.imgur.com/os6gD.png), however, when I try to get them by script I can't... it seems to me that the command "Get-MsolAccountSku" is synchronous and is not executed because it always has code to execute.
The "Get-MsolAccountSku" command just returns "Microsoft.Online.Administration.AccountSkuDetails" repeatedly for each of the licenses available in the tenant

###### function O365_GetAvailablelicenses() in image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9U4n.png

```
function O365_GetAvailablelicenses(){

    $allLicenses = Get-MsolAccountSku

    write-host "DEBUG_1_____________________________________________________"
    Write-Host "Output_#_$(Get-MsolAccountSku)"
    $allLicenses
    write-host "DEBUG_2_____________________________________________________"

    #A forma de criar uma tabela, foi consultada em https://www.ntweekly.com/2021/12/13/how-to-create-a-table-in-powershell/
    $licensesToDisplay = @()

    #Vai percorrer todas as licencas do tenant, e vai guardar numa tabela os campos Description,AccountSkuId,ActiveUnits,ConsumedUnits,AvailableUnits das licencas que estão na condição do primeiro IF dentro do FOREACH abaixo
    foreach($license in $allLicenses){

        if ($license.AccountSkuId -eq "reseller-account:EXCHANGESTANDARD" -or $license.AccountSkuId -eq "reseller-account:STANDARDPACK" -or $license.AccountSkuId -eq "reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK" -or $license.AccountSkuId -eq "reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPREMIUM" -or $license.AccountSkuId -eq "reseller-account:VISIOCLIENT") {
            
            $row = "" | Select-Object Description,AvailableUnits,AccountSkuId,ActiveUnits,ConsumedUnits
            if ($license.AccountSkuId -eq "reseller-account:EXCHANGESTANDARD") {$row.Description = "Exchange Online"}elseif ($license.AccountSkuId -eq "reseller-account:STANDARDPACK") {$row.Description = "Office E1"}elseif ($license.AccountSkuId -eq "reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK") {$row.Description = "Office E3"}elseif ($license.AccountSkuId -eq "reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPREMIUM") {$row.Description = "Office E5"}elseif ($license.AccountSkuId -eq "reseller-account:VISIOCLIENT") {$row.Description = "Visio Online"}
            $row.AccountSkuId = $license.AccountSkuId
            $row.ActiveUnits = $license.ActiveUnits
            $row.ConsumedUnits = $license.ConsumedUnits
            $row.AvailableUnits = $row.ActiveUnits - $row.ConsumedUnits
            
            $licensesToDisplay += $row
        }
    }

    write-host "DEBUG_3_____________________________________________________"
    $licensesToDisplay | Sort-Object -Property Description | Format-Table -AutoSize
    write-host "DEBUG_4_____________________________________________________"
    return $licensesToDisplay
}
```

Output of O365_GetAvailablelicenses(): https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU5tf.png

###### function O365_ReadLicenseToAssign() in image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MryFd.png

```
function O365_ReadLicenseToAssign(){
 
    $Availablelicenses = O365_GetAvailablelicenses
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "  Available licenses at $( Get-Date -Uformat “%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S  ")" -BackgroundColor DarkGray
    $Availablelicenses
    Write-Host "Should write the licenses here.($Availablelicenses)"
    $Availablelicenses | Sort-Object -Property Description | Format-Table -AutoSize

    do {
        $typeOflicenseToAssign = Read-Host -Prompt "Write the license name to assign"

        #Se por acaso o utilizador inserir por exemplo "Visio E1", o script vai pegar na primeira licença que sair no loop...
        foreach ($license in $Availablelicenses) {

            if ($license.Description -match $typeOflicenseToAssign) {
                [hashtable]$licenseToAssignToTheUser = @{ }
                $licenseToAssignToTheUser.AccountSkuId = $license.AccountSkuId
                $licenseToAssignToTheUser.Description = $license.Description
                break
            }
        }

        if ($null -eq $licenseToAssignToTheUser) {
            Write-Host "ERROR: None license matched the name $($typeOflicenseToAssign)" -ForegroundColor Red
        }

    } while ($null -eq $licenseToAssignToTheUser)
    return $licenseToAssignToTheUser
}
```

Output of O365_ReadLicenseToAssign(): https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU5tf.png

I've done a lot of tests and I can't get the value of "Get-MsolAccountSku" for the variable $allLicenses
I also leave two prints, one of the result of the script menu to assign licenses to users (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAQQi.png) and another of the result of the function in a powershell window (https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7uqi.png)

Honestly, I don't know what else I can do, and I thank you in advance for any help from you.
Regards, Rodrigo Simões

Comment: PLEASE ... fix your code formatting. right now it is nearly unreadable. the instructions for that are linked to in the page that you used to create your Question ... and in the Tour page for StackOverflow.

Comment: I made some changes, i hope you can understand the situation better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function 0365_GetAvailablelicenses {
    Get-MsolAccountSku | Where-Object AccountSkuId -in @(
        'reseller-account:EXCHANGESTANDARD'
        'reseller-account:STANDARDPACK'
        'reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK'
        'reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPREMIUM'
        'reseller-account:VISIOCLIENT'
    ) | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Description    = switch -Regex ($_.AccountSkuId) {
                'EXCHANGESTANDARD'  { 'Exchange Online' }
                'STANDARDPACK'      { 'Office E1' }
                'ENTERPRISEPACK'    { 'Office E3' }
                'ENTERPRISEPREMIUM' { 'Office E5' }
                'VISIOCLIENT'       { 'Visio Online' }
            }
            AccountSkuId   = $_.AccountSkuId
            ActiveUnits    = $_.ActiveUnits
            ConsumedUnits  = $_.ConsumedUnits
            AvailableUnits = $_.ActiveUnits - $_.ConsumedUnits
        }
    }
}
```

That function solved my problem. I cant get the PSObject at once.
After having that function, i received the array to an variable who calls the function